# What is the difference between MSSQL and TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

MSSQL and T-SQL are often thrown around as interchangeable synonyms on the web.

I know that T-SQL is a flavor of SQL used in many Microsoft products. Is MS-SQL actually another flavor of Microsoft owned SQL or is it just an umbrella term used by the Microsoft’s marketing department to refer to their server database solutions?

As a side question, what flavor SQL, if any, does MS Access use?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`MS SQL` is simply a short version of the (complete) product name `Microsoft SQL Server`. (Similar to "MS Office", "MS Windows" or "MS Access").

T-SQL is the SQL dialect that the *product* `Microsoft SQL Server` is using - and is short for "Transact-SQL" (thanks Aaron for reminding me!)

I wouldn't call the dialect that Microsoft Access is using SQL. It's a query language that somehow *resembles* SQL

Comment: And T-SQL stands for Transact-SQL.

Comment: And MS-SQL is not a term used by Microsoft anywhere. I've mostly heard it from MySQL users and very rarely from actual SQL Server users.

Comment: And, very importantly, Sybase also implements T-SQL.  Some might say they invented it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the clarification

Comment: Doesn't access use jet engine sql?

Answer (score 4):

The MS SQL Stands for ( Microsoft SQL). This is the product of Microsoft which they released MS SQL 2005, 2008 and recently released 2012.

T- SQL stands for Transact SQL. This is the syntax of writing the expression in the sql database. You can write T- SQL statments in MS SQL Server Database

[Link to Refer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sqlserver/default.aspx)

Comment: The product name is **not** "MS SQL 2005" it's _MS SQL **Server** 2005_